# Java Process Builder always giving data in Error Stream

Tags: java, stream, processbuilder

I have following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(CMD_ARRAY);
process = pb.start();
FrameworkLogger.log("Waiting for 120 seconds");
boolean code = process.waitFor(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("code is "+code);
output = getStream(process.getInputStream());
System.out.println("getInputStream:"+output);
error = getStream(process.getErrorStream());
System.out.println("getErrorStream:"+error);


public String getStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br1 = null;
    String line;
    try {
         br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        line = null;
        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    } finally {
        br1.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I always get code to be true, but stream from getInputStream() is empty, and the desired stream is in getErrorStream(). Why could this be happening? How do I get the desired stream in getInputStream()?

Comment: Don't you need to use separate threads to capture all the stream output?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you elaborate with sample code?

Comment: Myself, I usually create a StreamGobbler class, one that implements Runnable to handle both streams

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572849/the-correct-way-to-handle-process-streams)

Comment: [Other similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+process+handle+streams+site:stackoverflow.com)